# Host sFlow on older Windows servers

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2000, sflow

Is it possible to install [Host sFlow](http://host-sflow.sourceforge.net/) to Windows Server 2000 and Windows server 2003?

I've setup [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) on one host to monitor a (mostly Windows) environment and while sFlow works on Win 2k8 machines, it does not on my legacy servers.
I just can't get the installation to do anything - when I start the installation, it immediately tells me that the process has prematurely ended.

Note: If sFlow can't work there, I'll accept an answer that suggests similar monitoring thingy that is willing to send data to Ganglia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two installers for host sFlow for Windows. hsflowd-winxp-<version>-x86.msi for older versions (eg Windows Server 2003), and hsflowd-win-<version>-x64.msi (or the 32 bit version) for Vista, Windows Server 2008 R2 and later.

If you are using the installer for older versions of Windows and still having problems, I suggest that you try running the install from the command line:
msiexec /i hsflowd-winxp-1.22.1-x86.msi /l*v msi.log

msi.log should then give us an idea about what the problem is. A posting to the host sFlow mailing list should be read by the host sFlow developers.

Comment: Thanks, this looks more promising then the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with this software, but I can see from looking at the [Windows installation instructions](http://blog.sflow.com/2010/10/installing-host-sflow-on-windows-server.html) that the screen shots are of a "legacy" version of Windows (looks like the XP Luna theme) so, at least at one time, the installer did work on Windows XP (and, therefore, likely works on Windows Server 2003).

I also see that the installation is MSI-based. That means you should be able to get some verbose logging information by [enabling verbose Windows Installer logging](https://serverfault.com/a/170051/7200) and looking at the resulting output file.

If you can pin down the failure in the MSI log post it as an edit to your question and we'll have a look. (I wouldn't post the entire log-- they're quite large, typically.)